# LongClick on subMenu item of overflow menu

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

I'm working on the project that has an overflow menu in the android app. in **onCreateOptionsMenu()** I dynamically update the menu and a submenu based on user details but the task requires me to have 2 actions with that menu button, I already have a single click via **onOptionsItemSelected()**

is it possible to add something like OnLongClickListener to an item of the sub-menu for the overflow menu?

In my menu XML I set the subItem like this

```
<item
android:id="@+id/help"
android:orderInCategory="101"
android:title="Help"
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
app:showAsAction="never" >
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        xmlns:HTMLCode="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/event1"
        android:title="Event 1"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        HTMLCode:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/event2"
        android:title="Event 2"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        HTMLCode:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/event3"
        android:title="Event 3"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        HTMLCode:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

then in the on onCreateOptionsMenu i attach longClick like this

```
    var helpMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.help)
helpMenuItem.subMenu?.let { subMenu ->
    val ct = subMenu.size()
    for (i in 0 until ct) {
        val subItem = subMenu.getItem(i)
        subItem.actionView?.let { view ->
            view.setOnLongClickListener {
                Log.d("Long Click Event", "I'm here!!")
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles but I was never able to get onLongClick. Please help have been looking for the solution for a few days wo luck

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370909/long-press-on-android-menu-item

Comment: I've seen it before and tried 2 solutions from that page, the code compiles but doesn't get to the longClick :/

Comment: I suspect android is blocking now that longClick on the menu. That menu I have is supposed to be updateable but then I need to have a way to remove those items too, the most native way I could think off was to do a longClick and allow removal in that case, but wo longClick i need to find a way to allow 2 events per 1 menuItem

Comment: check out this [answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899386/16930239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So no one answered but I need to get it done, so I kept on digging. this is the workaround solution I came up with. Instead of keeping the toolBar menu for the submenu, I create a new dialogue, there I overwrote and add my onClick and on LongClick. which did work for me, nothing else did.

```
private fun displayPopupDialog() {
    val context = applicationContext
    val buds = myArray.toTypedArray<CharSequence>()
    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Select a Buddy")
    builder.setItems(buds, object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(dialogInterface: DialogInterface?, item: Int) {
            //  showShortToast("Clicked on:"+buddy[item]);
            val ptcode = buds[item].toString()
                clickFromDialog("code: $ptcode")
            return
        }
    })
    val ad = builder.create() //don't show dialog yet
    ad.setOnShowListener(object : DialogInterface.OnShowListener {
        override fun onShow(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
            val lv = ad.listView //this is a ListView with your "buds" in it
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
                override fun onItemLongClick(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ): Boolean {
                    var textOnView = (view as MaterialTextView).text
                    Log.d("Long Click!", "List Item #" + position + " $textOnView was long clicked")
                    return true
                }
            })
        }
    })


    val window: Window? = ad.getWindow()
    val wlp: LayoutParams? = window?.getAttributes()
    wlp?.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.TOP
    window?.setAttributes(wlp)
    ad.show()
}

private fun clickFromDialog(ptcode: String) {
    Log.d("Click!", "List Item $ptcode was clicked")
}
```